# Streamlit app tries to find a different font path than the written on the script

Tags: python, download, fpdf, streamlit

I've been working on a streamlit app that make a pdf report. The issue here is when I run it in my computer everything is ok. But when I sent to a coworker doesn't work properly the app is trying to find a font path which is not in the script because we rewrote in order that runs properly in her computer.

1. my_path/font.tff
2. her_path/font.tff

The scrip tries to find the first, even though we already changed.

The error is in the download button, but as you may see there is not font path there.

```
st.download_button(
        'Download Report',
        data=pdf.output(dest='S').encode('latin-1'),
        file_name=f'fint_test_{nombre.title()}_{user}.pdf'
        )
    
    return
```

Did anybody had to face a similar issue?

Find the way to edit a hidden path or solve it.

Comment: Are you sure the code is updated on your coworker's machine?

Comment: Maybe you have to embed the font in the pdf https://www.printivity.com/insights/how-to-embed-fonts-in-pdfs/